# General Setup on remote programming

Tags: ssh-tunneling

I have the following 3 units

- A laptop that runs both MAC/Ubuntu
- A home-based server with Ubuntu desktop version
- A wireless router which I got from the provider that does not have that much technical documentation (just general setup stuff). Also the router is connected with wire to the server.

Ideally I want to use the terminal on my laptop and connect to the home server. What are the options? I just need to setup an SSH connection between these two machines?

Comment: yes. you probably have to forward port 22 (tcp) from your router to your server.

Comment: Playing with the router scares me!. How can I do that?. Also just knowing the ip address is enough to connect to the router?.

Comment: @asgharashgari: Yes, knowing your public IP or a dynamic DNS name that is updated by your router is enough. Port forwarding configuration differs from router to router, you can probably find a user guide for your model in the internet, if you don't have the manual any more.

Answer (score 0):

Look for port forwarding or port triggering or "NAT" or a similar term in the router interface. Forward port 22 (or whatever you have moved it to if you have moved it) to the IP of your Ubuntu server. You will want to set a static IP for the Ubuntu server.

Once you have the SSH up and running and can be reachable on the outside, you can forward just about any port from the machine you are working on to the Ubuntu server, or anything on the same network with it.

Be aware that some ISP's tend to juggle IP addresses for regular home users, so you may want to look into something like DynDNS service, or write your own probing script to email you, etc. if your home IP address changes.